# Unable to type letter 't' in Webstorm terminal

Tags: terminal, webstorm

I am facing a very weird issue with Webstorm. I am unable to enter letter 't' inside the terminal within Webstorm. There is no issue if I type within the code editor or elsewhere. But I have no clue why this is happening? Not sure if anything is related to tab because when it has some predefined words for git or other things it give suggestions. But when I am trying to create new file or name with 't', nothing is happening.

Checked even the settings, but not sure what is happening as I am new to this IDE. Has anyone faced this issue?